# Cannot find symbol: barkOnce() of location: variable d of type Object

Tags: java, object, compiler-errors

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Object d = new Dog();
       d.barkOnce();
    }
}

class Dog
{
    private String voice;

    public void barkOnce()
    {
        System.out.println(voice);
    }
 }
```

When ever I run the program, I get an error in my output:

exit status 1
Main.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
   d.barkOnce();
    ^
  symbol:   method barkOnce()
  location: variable d of type Object

After analyzing the error, I was clueless as to why the method couldn't be found. Can someone possibly explain what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Method `barkOnce()` is not part of the type `Object`. You should be able to compile with:

`Dog d = new Dog()`

When you cast to a base like Object, the compiler blocks you from using anything on the more specific type, unless you typecast back.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you declared the variable "d" as type Object. Object does not have a barkOnce() method. You can cast it to Dog:

```
((Dog) d).barkOnce();
```

or declare it a Dog to begin with:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
```